# Solving non-quadratic equations with mutliple solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

> Given that there is more than one solution value of $x$ to the equation $4^{ax} = b \times8^x$, find all possible values of $a$ and $b$.

While I understand majority of the approach to solve this question, outlined in the steps below, the reasoning for calculating all the possible values of $a$ and $b$ isn't apparent to me - which is the last step.

$4^{ax} = b \times8^x$ can be simplified by:

$(2^2)^{ax} = b \times (2^3)^x\\ 2^{2ax} = b \times 2^{3x}\\ \log_2(2^{2ax}) = \log_2(b\times2^{3x})\\ 2ax = \log_2(b) + 3x \\ x(2a-3) = \log_2(b)$

The question states that there are more than one solution values of $x$, to find the value of $a$ and $b$ the solution indicates to equate the simplified equation to $0$.

$2a-3=\log_2(b)=0$

This yields $a$ as $3/2$ and $b$ as $1$. I understand how placing these values in the above equation will equate it to $0$. What confuses me is why $x$ was removed in order to find the solution. Also, is there any general approach to solve such questions?

Comment: If $a=\frac32;\;b=1$ the given equation becomes $8^x=8^x$ which is verified for any $x$. And no, there is no general methods. It depends on the equation.

Answer (score 1):

From $x(2a-3)=\log_2(b)$ (let call this equation (*))

If $2a-3\ne0$ then you can solve this equation $x=\frac{\log_2b}{2a-3}$ and the solution is UNIQUE. So $2a-3$ HAVE TO be zero if you want more than one solution.

BUT in this case, (*) can be written as $0=\log_2b$.

So, the ONLY possibility for your initial equation to have more than one solution is that b$2a-3=0=\log_2 b$.